# JS web framework with transparent/autogenerated client-server data layer

Tags: javascript, web, web-frameworks

I'm wondering if there's a JS web framework with transparent/autogenerated data layer? To save my time, so I don't have to write all the code by myself.

Let's say I'm writing React Blog app, and communicate with the server using REST API.

I need to write two pieces of data layer, the server side, and its client on the client side.

Something like code below:

1 The business logic itself, resides on the server side:

```
class BlogAPI {
  async getPosts() {
    const records = await db.query('select * from posts')
    return convertRecordsIntoPostObjects(records)
  }
}
```

2 Exposing business logic as REST API and writing its client on the client side:

```
// REST API, this code also resides on the server side.
httpServer.get('/posts', () => blogApi.getPosts())

// And writing a client for it, that code resides on the client side.
class BlogAPIClient {
  async getPosts() {
    http.get('http://server-api-endpoint.com/posts')
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there are web frameworks where part 2 is somehow magically autogenerated, so I can save my time and write only
the business logic.

P.S. Don't mention GraphQL, it's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Not exactly, but checkout my framework: https://firefight.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Meteor looks like what you are looking for: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections . Also you may wish to take a look at Parse Server https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#getting-started (and maybe also Firebase, but it's neither customizable nor self-hosted/opensource)